# csv file & displaying usage per hours

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have a CSV file that captures per user usage per hour

user1, datetime, TRUE/FALSE

eg:

```
jon, 03/06/2017 12:00, 1
mark, 03/06/2017 12:00, 1
jon, 03/06/2017 13:00, 1
```

I am struggling to represent this to show usage per hour.

What I would like to create in matlab is a cumulative count per hour. From the above snippit:

```
03/06/2017 12:00, 2
03/06/2017 13:00, 1
```

From this hourly usage can be shown.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I don't understand what the `TRUE/FALSE` is for. Are you hoping to plot number of users online vs hour?

Comment: apologies... the description was not that clear. I would like to plot the number of users per hour.  The True/False is actually a 1,0 so summation is a bit simpler.  I can represent the data in Excel as a pivot table, however this should be doable in Excel

Comment: you can convert your dates into epoch and then round to nearest hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

1. [`unique`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to find all unique hours in your csv file
2. Use [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) to select all rows corresponding with a given hour
3. Use [`sum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) to find the number of active users, i.e. summing up the third column.